# Facebook share post dialog not showing post information

Tags: facebook

I recently created a new blog in Wordpress.com and wanted to share my post with my Facebook friends. When I tried to post using the Facebook share from my post, the "Share on Facebook" page opens with the message `http://myblog.wordpress.com is marked private by its owner. If you were invited to view this site, please log in below. Read more about privacy settings.`

I checked the blog's settings in **Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading**. `Site visibility` option is set as `Allow search engines to index this site`. Am I missing some configuration?

Here is a screenshot of the Facebook dialog I am getting.
[image]

Comment: Facebook cache had to be cleared. This happened because I had my blog set to Private previously. Followed this blog post to solve this - [http://umairj.com/146/how-to-clear-facebook-shares-cache/](http://umairj.com/146/how-to-clear-facebook-shares-cache/)

Comment: If you have fixed it, then add it as an answer and accept it which will help others with similar situation. The answer in the comment section might get lost.

Comment: @MarutiMohanty Thanks for pointing it out. Added it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook cache had to be cleared. This happened because I had my blog set to Private previously. Followed this blog post to solve this - http://umairj.com/146/how-to-clear-facebook-shares-cache/